# Error with simple print_r() code

Tags: php

I have problem with that code so please send me answer as soon as possible.

```
echo "<pre >";print_r($q) echo"</pre>";
```

Comment: There is SO much wrong with this question I don't know where to start. Please read the FAQ as soon as possible.

Comment: What is the code supposed to do?  You didn't give us much other then the code isn't working and you want us to fix it for you.  What have you tried?  What is happening?  All of these things help make the question a little easier for us to help you.

Comment: Use One liner Code `echo "<pre >",print_r($q),"</pre>";`

Answer (score 4):

Correct format to print reocrds is

```
echo "<pre>";
 print_r($q);
echo"</pre>";
```

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the delimiter ';' after print_r

```
echo "<pre >"; print_r($q); echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 3):

plase add semi column (';') after print_r statement

```
echo "<pre >";print_r($q); echo"</pre>";
```